# FirebaseAuth throws error when I called currentUser and Observable error in rxdart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have created an app with Google login with firestore support and recently I have updated all the dependencies to a newer version. Here There are some problem with the old code I don't know what's the problem.

```
Future<String> getCurrentUser() async {
    var user = await _auth.currentUser();
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return user.uid;
    }
}
```

It shows error near _auth.currentUser(); and the error is `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.` I have searched for it but nothing worked. This is the First problem.

The Second problem arises with `rxdart` package. Due to new packages `Observable` is not supported and Searched it for internet and tried using `Stream` But they are not working.
The Source Code is here for rxdart problem.

```
class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<User> user;
  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> profile;
  String uuid;

  AuthService() {
    Stream<User> user = Observable(_auth.authStateChanges);

    profile = user.switchMap((User u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

It shows error near `return Observable.just({});` and next problem arises with this line `Stream<User> user = Observable(_auth.authStateChanges);`

Help me sort this out and Help me understand my issues.

Comment: Answer to your first question is below. I'd recommend opening a second question for your other problem, as it  is unrelated (and I don't immediately know the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentUser` is no longer a method, and no longer asynchronous. So the correct invocation now is:

```
var user = _auth.currentUser;
```

I recommend keeping the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration#authentication) handy while upgrading your code to this latest version, as there are quite a few of these changes.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of the Firebase Auth SDK for Flutter, if you want a stream of auth state events, you should set up an auth state stream using [authStateChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html), as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state).

> ```
> FirebaseAuth.instance
>   .authStateChanges()
>   .listen((User user) {
>     if (user == null) {
>       print('User is currently signed out!');
>     } else {
>       print('User is signed in!');
>     }
>   });
> ```